# How to debug Protractor e2e tests with ndb?

Tags: node.js, protractor, google-chrome-devtools

I have recently discovered the magic of debugging Node applications with [ndb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndb). (You should really check it out, if you've never seen it.)
For our non-e2e integration tests (which use jasmine) I was easily able to debug the test code simply by substituting `ndb` for `node`.

```
ndb node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js --config=jasmine.json
```

When I do the same for protractor, the debugger comes up, but the tests don't begin. For example, the following fails:

```
ndb node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.ts --suite smoke
```

Any clues? (I have a suspicion that it has to do with the Typescript transpilation that happens, but I have no evidence hard evidence.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem by more trial-and-error. I do not understand why this makes a difference, but the following variation on the `ndb` command worked:

```
ndb node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.ts --suite smoke
```

According to `ndb --help`, ndb provides several variations on how to kick off debug sessions. Like I said, I'm not sure why the `ndb node` flavor worked while straight `ndb` failed.

Comment: More recent Protractor documentation shows a CLI incantation to start protractor in debug mode. From http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging:

`protractor debug debugging/failureConf.js`

(Note: I haven't tried this myself. Just reporting what I saw in the docs.)